# Centering Sub-Menus - not centering

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center submenus under their parent menu but I can't seem to find the correct coding. I have tried "transform: translate(-50%,0);" but it doesn't seem to be having any effect. Below is the original css, without any coding attempting to center. Any help would be great!

For reference, my project is lightertaste.com

```css
.genesis-nav-menu {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: right;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: normal;
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
 font-family: 'dosis';
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: .5px;
 text-align: left;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a {
 padding: 0px 10px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #abc3b7;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu a:focus,
.genesis-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:focus {
 color: #585858;
}

/* Sub Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu:before {
 display: none;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
 z-index: 2000;
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 width: 125px;
 border: none;
 opacity: 0;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
 position: relative;
 width: 125px;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #6f9985;
 text-align: center;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
 margin: -41px 0 0 125px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover {
 position: static;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:focus,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:focus {
 background: #6f9985;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu  {
 opacity: 1;
 left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-886" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-886"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/shop/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Shop</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-885" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-885"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/resources/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Resources</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-882" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-882"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/contact/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Contact</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-887" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-887"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/work-with-me/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Work With Me</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Use `absolute` positioning to move the elements `relative` to the main `li`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
transform: translateX(-1.3em);
```

To the following:

```
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu, .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu, .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        left: auto;
        transform: translateX(-1.3em);
    }
```